# How to Deploy a Build in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I just started using Visual Studio Online, and figured out how to create builds online.  I need the build deployed to Azure, but I see that the builds still need to be deployed.  There is a Deployed tab with nothing under it, which just says "no builds have been deployed today by anyone".  How do I deploy the builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Deployed tab is if you are setting up the [continuous deployment workflow to Azure as described here](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/deploy-to-azure-vs).

Another method is trying the Release Management Service in Visual Studio Online and you can [get started here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/manage-your-release-vs.aspx). You will need Visual Studio Premium or Visual Studio Ultimate to get access to the release management workflow definition experience for this option.

Comment: I did try the first method but I got hung up because I see no option for "Create release definition" as described (using Express for Web 2013 Update 4).  I also tried the second method but I'm having trouble figuring out how the credentials work.  It helps knowing I'm heading in the right direction though.

Comment: @Dave - you're right.  Creating releases is part of Visual Studio Premium or Visual Studio Ultimate.  We don't currently include it in either Visual Studio Community or the legacy Visual Studio Express editions.  Keep going with the first route at the moment.  What about the credentials are confusing?  Thankfully, the wizard sets up the authentication handshake between Visual Studio Online and Azure.

Comment: Ed, I'm good to go now but at first, in RMC, I guess I wasn't following the directions and clicked on the Manage Azure tab.  It seemed like the thing to do.  There, it asks for "Management Certificate Key" and I tried but could not find that key anywhere in Azure.  Also... I installed a copy of Premium from work but still have no "Create release definition" option in VS (maybe because the project was created in Express).  It would be nice if VS would make it clear if an option exists but is not available in Express.  But it doesn't matter, I've got everything running that's needed now.

Comment: @Dave - great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ed's steps, I found that since I created the project initially in Visual Studio, not Azure, I then had to go to Azure, and select "**Set up deployment from source control**", then select Visual Studio Online.  Azure then asks for the URL of my Visual Studio Online account, and connects the two.  Now all the connections are made and deployment can be initiated from VSO or VS when commits are made if that option is selected.

I never found the "Create release definition" option as described in the documentation.  But it turns out I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

For the newest **Visual Studio 2022 to Azure DevOps** version, here is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578304/5555938